# How to configure sh_test dependencies in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have a test1 which is a sh_test and a test2 sh_test that depends on test1 but I can't seem to add test1 as a dependency to test2.  Is there any way to only run test2 if test1 completes and is successful?

Comment: `sh_test` can only depend (`deps`) on `sh_library`. If you need something to run the test, you can declare such dependency as `data`, but that would do you no good making it depend on another `sh_test` target. So I do not think you can, but also the use case sounds a bit unusual. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more about what you're trying to achieve in your question?

Comment: test1 produces a lot of output files which in turn are used by test2.  test1 despite it's role as I describe should be treated as a test as well.

Comment: Hmm, not sure that's how test was intended to be used. Could the artifact(s) generating bit be refactored out of test1 so that it could become a "proper" dependency of both tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split test1 into two parts:

- the "build" part: the build rules that produces the outputs that test2 needs to consume
- the "assertion" part: whatever assertions the test is making

The test rules (test1 and test2) can depend on the genrule and test the correctness of the outputs.